# R ggplot2: Add means as horizontal line in a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have created a boxplot using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(study = c(rep('a',50),rep('b',50)), 
                  FPKM = c(rnorm(1:50),rnorm(1:50)))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = study, y = FPKM)) + geom_boxplot()
```

The boxplot shows the median as a horizontal line across each box.

[image]

How do I add a dashed line to the box representing the mean of that group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can add horizontal lines to plots by using `stat_summary` with `geom_errorbar`.  The line is horizontal because the y minimum and maximum are set to be the same as y.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = study, y = FPKM)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
                 width = .75, linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: Just like to add that using ggplot's new syntax, the following will also work with scale transformations: `stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.min = mean, fun = mean, fun.max = mean, width = .75)`