# Add segments with width relative to the width of the bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following data:

```
behaviorm <- structure(list(sentential_connective = c("IF", "IF",
"Because", "IF", "Because", "IF", "Because", "IF", "IF", "Because", "IF", 
"Because", "IF", "Because", "IF", "IF", "Because", "IF", "Because", 
"IF", "Because", "IF", "IF", "Because", "IF", "Because", "IF", 
"Because"), mentioned_object = c("Same", "Different", "Same", 
"Same", "Same", "Different", "Different", "Same", "Different", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Different", "Different", "Same", "Different", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Different", "Different", "Same", "Different", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Different", "Different"), 
agent_mood = c("Sad", "Sad", "Happy", "Happy", "Sad", "Happy", 
"Happy", "Sad", "Sad", "Happy", "Happy", "Sad", "Happy", "Happy", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Happy", 
"Happy", "Sad", "Happy", "Happy", "Sad", "Sad", "Happy", "Happy", 
"Sad", "Happy", "Happy"), Chosen_Box = c("SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", 
"SD", "SD", "SD", "CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", "SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD", 
"DD", "DD"), chose_action = c(500L, 80L, 7L, 11L, 755L, 236L, 
7L, 74L, 631L, 21L, 484L, 29L, 38L, 1L, 8L, 81L, 786L, 321L, 
7L, 6L, 14L, 247L, 25L, 13L, 9L, 36L, 538L, 801L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the following data:

```
chance_level <- structure(list(sentential_connective = c("Because", "Because", 
"Because", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF"), mentioned_object = c("Different", 
"Same", "Same", "Different", "Different", "Same", "Same"), agent_mood = c("Happy", 
"Happy", "Sad", "Happy", "Sad", "Happy", "Sad"), chance = c(205.75, 
206.75, 206.75, 204.5, 204.25, 206.25, 207.25), xmin = c(0.55, 
0.55, 0.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55), xmax = c(1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 
2.45, 2.45, 2.45, 2.45)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

And my graph is as follows:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x = sentential_connective, y = chose_action, fill = Chosen_Box),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9, preserve = "single"),
    data = behaviorm
  ) + 
  facet_grid(agent_mood ~ mentioned_object) + 
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = chance, yend = chance),
    data = chance_level, lwd = 0.2, lty = 2
  ) + 
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    axis.line = element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black"),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
    strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0)
  )
```

As being illustrated in the script, I can add the wides of the `segments` **manually** with the _x_s and _xend_s provided in the `chance_level` file.

My question is: Can we **automatically** set the horizontal position and width of these segments relative to the width of the bar graphs?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please draw on the picture what you would like to see? I didn't fully follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the attached image is the one I want, but I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient way to achieve this, where I didn't need to manually provide the xs and xends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `stat_summary()`. The use of `..y..` means, "whatever the value of y is".

```r
ggplot(behaviorm, aes(x = sentential_connective, y = chose_action)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(fill = Chosen_Box),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")
  ) +
  facet_grid(agent_mood ~ mentioned_object) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.y = mean, aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
    geom = "errorbar", linetype = "dashed"
  )
```

I found this solution here:
[R ggplot2: Add means as horizontal line in a boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135240/r-ggplot2-add-means-as-horizontal-line-in-a-boxplot)